# React Native Android app crashing in emulator but in real device working fine

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

**When running project in emulator crashing,
but in real device working fine.**

i recently updated to API level 33 for Push Notification Alert Permission.

Any suggestion on this ?

***below is the log***

```
08/18 14:36:02: Launching 'app' on Pixel 5 API 33.
Install successfully finished in 1 s 423 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 21346 on device 'Pixel_5_API_33 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10194; state: ENABLED
D/nativeloader: Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.myapp
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
D/nativeloader: Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.myapp
V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.myapp' set to: 'default'
V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE GameManagerService for com.myapp: false
V/GraphicsEnvironment: Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10194; state: ENABLED
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
I/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.2.13 for com.myapp
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/DynamiteLoader.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/DynamiteLoader.dm': No such file or directory
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:83 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:87
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 87
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
D/ReactNativeFirebaseApp: received application context.
D/RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled via RNFBMeta: true
D/RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled after checking crashlytics_debug_enabled: false
D/RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled final value: false
I/RNFBCrashlyticsInit: initialization successful
D/libcrashlytics: Initializing libcrashlytics version 3.2.0
D/SoLoader: init start
D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /vendor/lib64
D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /system/lib64
D/SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
D/SoLoader: adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.myapp/lib-main flags = 1]
D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.myapp/lib-main flags = 1]
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.myapp/lib-main
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: deps mismatch on deps store: regenerating
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: so store dirty: regenerating
D/libcrashlytics: Initializing native crash handling successful.
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000007/MeasurementDynamite.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000007/MeasurementDynamite.dm': No such file or directory
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics-common.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics-handler.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics-trampoline.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libevent-2.1.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libevent_core-2.1.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libevent_extra-2.1.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libfb.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libfbjni.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libflipper.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libfolly_futures.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libfolly_json.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libglog.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libglog_init.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libhermes-executor-debug.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libhermes-executor-release.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libhermes-inspector.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libimagepipeline.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libjniPdfium.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so: deferring to libdir
V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libjscexecutor.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libjsijniprofiler.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libjsinspector.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libmodft2.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libmodpdfium.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libmodpng.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libnative-filters.so: deferring to libdir
V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.myapp, 1:656666692293:android:277808fc4c4786c95a7eac
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libnative-imagetranscoder.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libreactnativeblob.so: deferring to libdir
I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 75066
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libreactnativejni.so: deferring to libdir
D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/arm64-v8a/libyoga.so: deferring to libdir
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.myapp
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: regenerating DSO store com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: Finished regenerating DSO store com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: starting syncer worker
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.myapp/lib-main (from syncer thread)
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: not releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.myapp/lib-main (syncer thread started)
D/SoLoader: init finish: 4 SO sources prepared
D/SoLoader: init exiting
D/FA: Resetting session stitching token to not null
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/SoLoader: init exiting
D/SoLoader: About to load: libjscexecutor.so
D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.myapp/lib-main
D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so found on /data/app/~~BwKVlvzJ328cx_mh1xQXxg==/com.myapp-tKE0ZuflGt9skQpEPFp-nA==/lib/arm64
D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libjscexecutor.so
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/JavaScriptCore.Version: 245459.0.0
D/SoLoader: Loaded: libjscexecutor.so
D/SoLoader: init exiting
W/m.myapp: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (max-target-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

**and here is the Fatal Exception Logs**

**and here is the Fatal Exception Logs**

**and here is the Fatal Exception Logs**

**and here is the Fatal Exception Logs**

**and here is the Fatal Exception Logs**

**and here is the Fatal Exception Logs**

**and here is the Fatal Exception Logs**

**and here is the Fatal Exception Logs**

**and here is the Fatal Exception Logs**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 21346
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.myapp.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6764)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevSupportManagerFactory.java:90)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:237)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:280)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:87)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:39)
        at com.myapp.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:53)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1277)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6759)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevSupportManagerFactory.java:80)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:237) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:280) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:87) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:39) 
        at com.myapp.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:53) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1277) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6759) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.get(Platform.java:85)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:263)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:229)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:1015)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper.<init>(DevServerHelper.java:129)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase.<init>(DevSupportManagerBase.java:157)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl.<init>(DevSupportManagerImpl.java:72)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevSupportManagerFactory.java:80) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:237) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:280) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:87) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:39) 
        at com.myapp.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:53) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1277) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6759) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 33
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.buildIfSupported(AndroidPlatform.java:238)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.findPlatform(Platform.java:202)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:79)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.get(Platform.java:85) 
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:263) 
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:229) 
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:1015) 
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper.<init>(DevServerHelper.java:129) 
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase.<init>(DevSupportManagerBase.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl.<init>(DevSupportManagerImpl.java:72) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevSupportManagerFactory.java:80) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:237) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:280) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:87) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:39) 
        at com.myapp.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:53) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1277) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6759) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
D/TrafficStats: tagSocket(70) with statsTag=0x8001, statsUid=-1
D/libcrashlytics: Initializing libcrashlytics version 3.2.0
D/libcrashlytics: Initializing native crash handling successful.
```

Comment: Check your Konto version (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28481#issuecomment-645546195)